# Set Default Guard After Register/Login When Using Multiple Guards in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

I am working on a Laravel API project where the user's table has a column of type with a value of either student or company.

For the purpose of authenticating the users of both types and restricting access to certain routes, I have set up two guards with the same driver (JWT) and provider (Users).

```
       'company' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
```

In the login and register method of my controller, I am accessing the value of user type from the form where the user selects his role (student or company).

```
public function register(){

        $user= $this->create(request()->all());
        $token=auth(request('type'))->login($user);
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);


    }
```

The purpose to access the user type is to pass that value to the auth() method which in turn uses it to log in the user through that specific guard.

The issue is: I have to use that request(type) in every controller method wherever authentication is necessary and there is need to use use the auth() related methods. e.g jwt respondwithtoken() method

```
protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth(request('type'))->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }
```

What I want: I want a mechanism to set the guard dynamically after the user has successfully logged in and I should able be to use the auth() method without passing any argument to it.

```
// shoulduseguarddynamically(request('type'));
```

P.S: Please also verify that using guards in this way when I have single table with multi-type users is the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your approach is not really safe - just tampering with the 'type' will grant you access to places you are not supposed to go.

You would be better using Gates instead of guards for this, 
You can check them in the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#gates

Comment: +Christophe using gate "instead" of guards or "with" guards? Because I don't think so the gate is an alternative for guards. Guards are for authentication and gates are for authorization.

Comment: Since you are using the same model and the same auth - you don't really need to use different guards. Using Gates will be able to control if your user is allowed to access a certain resource